# How to type backslash in Russian on Macbook pro

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

I can't find the backslash key
either in low case or upper case(by holding shift key)
in Russian input method( I chose it on input source) on Macbook pro.

But if I choose russian pc input method, there is no "e with two dots above", but in the place having slash and backslash.

Any one has a solution to this typing problem?

Comment: You mean like this /  фтв \ щк ї щк ЎЌ щк  Ë

Comment: @Buscar Which keyboard layout are you using and which keys?  Without that info your comment doesn't help someone else type the same thing.

Comment: Rusian PC keyboard !?

Comment: @Buscar And are you also able to tell us which key you used to make the ё, as was requested?

Comment: ыщккяб цфы игыыя шт фтщерук здфсуб Ш гуыв еру КгышфтЗС фтв фкд sorry I was busy in another place, I used Russian PC and ctrl for the backslash and the ё is is in top left under esc.

Comment: as Requested ?????

Comment: @Buscar Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately the ё is only on that key when you have a European hardware keyboard.  On a US keyboard that key makes ] and the ё is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Russian Phonetic, option/alt + shift on the rightmost key on the bottom row.

I think to have the ё on Russia PC, you need to have an ISO keyboard (one with an extra key between the z and shift).

Some time ago I made a Russian PC layout where that character is more accessible.  If you want to try it (not sure it still works), go to

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46870715/k/RussianPC2.keylayout

Comment: Thanks. How do I install RussianPC2.keylayout on Mac?

Comment: Put the .keylayout file in Library/Keyboard Layouts or Home/Library/Keyboard Layouts, logout/login, check the box in system prefs/language & Text/Input Sources, select in the "flag" menu at top right of the screen.

Comment: It works and it's exactly the same as "QStamina", which is a typing russian exercise program. Thanks!