# How to type in citation letter in Russian on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

I want to type in the citation `«` in my Russian keyboard but I cannot find [any key combination to type it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/87993/5472).

How can I type it in macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several Russian input sources, how you type things depends on which one you are using:

Russian Phonetic:  « » are at option o and option p.

Russian:  option = and option shift =

Russian PC:  option ж and option shift  ж

For any character, you can use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/11.0/mac/11.0).